# SSAS: Measure added to an existing working Measure Group not showing values

Tags: ssas, cube, bids, olap-cube, measures

I added two measures to an existing measure group, the old measures work correctly, the new measures show 0.

I have tried the following:

1. Deleting and Redeploying the cube
2. Re-processing the partitions
3. Changed cube to Full Process
4. Changed a dimension that was referenced to be aggregated
5. Processed the dimensions individually, then the Cube
6. Deleted the partitions, created new ones, created aggregations

[Explore Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc4cA.png)

[Cube View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzRaA.png)

Comment: When you explore the table in the DSV does the Amount column have values on the same row as Solicitation_Gift_Amount? Or are they on separate rows?

Comment: On the new measures what is AggregateFunction set to? Hopefully Sum like the Amount measure and not something unusual like None. Did you do anything different like setting a MeasureExpression?

Comment: There are rows that have an Amount with a Solicitation_Gift_Amount, but most rows do not have a value.

Comment: The AggregateFunction is set to sum for the two new measures.

Comment: on the few rows that have both does the new measure show in the cube (if you filter to that portion of the cube)?

Comment: If I drag the measure over without any filters, it shows 0.  But, I noticed that the amount is not showing when I am expecting to see a value for Solicitation_Gift_Amount.  This is odd unexpected behavior.

Comment: Can you paste the entirety of your Calculations tab MDX script into the question?

Comment: I updated my original post with the screenshots showing the unexpected results.

Comment: The MDX script in the Calculations tab is just "CALCULATE" (minus the double quotes)

Comment: are you sure that the rows which have both measures are not being lost during processing. Can you see an amount if you filter to a portion of the cube? Wondering if ErrorConfiguration settings drop a row which doesn't match a dimension.

Comment: I appreciate your help in troubleshooting, it helped me to find the issue.  The fact table was linked to the date table through a regular relationship, so the facts that didn't have a date were not showing